# Some text rows longer than others

Tags: text

In my report, some lines are bigger than the others as it can be seen in the image. I have seen some solution in other questions but the problem is still continue. Could you help me please to find the problem out?

I have tried `\hyphenation{op-er-and op-er-ands}` but still the problem exists.

[image]

Comment: why do you set a hyphenation pattern for operand if the problem is with Levenberg-Marquardt?

Comment: `(Leven\-berg-Marquardt)` should get you out of the present predicament, unless your document parameters (which you have not provided) are odd.  If the hyphenation issue occurs with an overrun in Marquardt, then you have to reset the hyphenation algorithm with `(Levenberg-\hspace{0pt}Marquardt)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you so much it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While one can set hyphenation patterns that hold through the whole document, a problem that only arises once can be dealt with at the point of occurrence.  In this case, the algorithm did not know how to hyphenate "Levenberg", so I helped it by adding a momentary hyphenation point with `\-`.

If the problem had occurred in "Marquardt", there is a secondary issue.  That is, the hyphen in the middle of the word prevents the algorithm from even looking for a hyphenation in the second part.  Thus, to reset the algorithm, introduce a `\hspace{0pt}` after the mid-word hyphen.  If there were *still* a problem after that, then hyphenation points could also be introduced into "Marquardt" as was done with "Levenberg".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}

After checking every backpropagation algorithm that exist in MATLAB,
\textit{trainlm (Levenberg-Marquardt)} has been chosen.

After checking every backpropagation algorithm that exist in MATLAB,
\textit{trainlm (Leven\-berg-Marquardt)} has been chosen.
 
xx every backpropagation algorithm that exist in MATLAB,
\textit{trainlm (Levenberg-Marquardt)} has been chosen.

xx every backpropagation algorithm that exist in MATLAB,
\textit{trainlm (Levenberg-\hspace{0pt}Marquardt)} has been chosen.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works and thank you so much. I marked as an accepted answer.

Comment: @OğuzKAHRAMAN Thank you for that consideration.  Glad I could help.